# How to set the vertical scale in Google Charts

Tags: google-visualization, linechart

I have created a Google Chart Line Chart. There are data points at the bottom that do not show up because the upper points are large.

Here's my visualization function:

```
  function drawVisualization() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(#table#);
          var ac = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    ac.draw(data, {
      title : 'Billing Trend for this Month: #date#',
      isStacked: true,
      width: 1200,
      height: 1000,
      vAxis: {title: "Amount"},
      hAxis: {title: "Date"}
    });
  }
```

I've looked through the param list but cannot find the proper one to set.

I would like the lower data points to be discernible.

Has anyone had luck with trying to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `vAxis.logScale` option to true, which will change the axis scale from linear to logarithmic.  Your smaller values should then be discernible.  There are a few other methods you could try as well (changing the value used to draw the data while keeping the tooltips the same; using a panel chart that zooms in on lower values); see some examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/b4yCL/